# All weights after training become negative

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, entropy

I'm making a neural network. The training output for all pairs is either 0 or 1. I've noticed that if I add only a single training pair with target output '1' and 9 other pairs with '0', my weights after training all become negative, however if I increase the number of '1' target outputs in the training set, I see positive weights as well.

A training set that gives all negative weights:
INPUT:

```
[[0.46       0.4        0.98039216]
 [0.58       0.         0.98039216]
 [0.2        1.         0.39215686]
 [0.1        0.4        0.45960784]
 [0.74       0.53333333 0.19607843]
 [0.48       0.93333333 0.        ]
 [0.38       0.7        0.98039216]
 [0.02       0.53333333 1.        ]
 [0.         0.03333333 0.88235294]
 [1.         0.8        0.78431373]]
```

OUTPUT:

```
[[0.][0.][0.][0.][0.][0.][0.][0.][0.][1.]]
```

WEIGHTS BEFORE TRAINING (RANDOM):

```
[[-0.16595599]
 [ 0.44064899]
 [-0.99977125]]
```

WEIGHTS AFTER TRAINING:

```
[[-1.48868116]
 [-4.8662876 ]
 [-5.42639621]]
```

However, if I change target outputs by one more '1' as such

```
[[0.][0.][0.][0.][0.][0.][0.][0.][0.][1.]]
```

I get a positive weight as well after training:

```
[[ 1.85020129]
 [-1.9759502 ]
 [-1.03829837]]
```

What could be the reason for this? Could it be that too many '0' make the '1' insignificant when training? If so, how should I change the approach when training? I want to use this training with a training set with around 480 training pairs with output '0' and 20 with '1'

(I'm using a sigmoid function:)

Full code:

```
from numpy import exp, array, random, dot
from collections import defaultdict
import csv
import numpy as np

class NeuralNetwork():
    def __init__(self):

        random.seed(1)

        self.synaptic_weights = 2 * random.random((3, 1)) - 1

    def __sigmoid(self, x):
        return 1 / (1 + exp(-x))

    def __sigmoid_derivative(self, x):
        return x * (1 - x)

    def train(self, training_set_inputs, training_set_outputs, number_of_training_iterations):
        for iteration in range(number_of_training_iterations):

            output = self.think(training_set_inputs)
            error = training_set_outputs - output
            adjustment = training_set_inputs.T.dot(error * self.__sigmoid_derivative(output))

            self.synaptic_weights += adjustment


    def think(self, inputs):
        return self.__sigmoid(dot(inputs, self.synaptic_weights))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    neural_network = NeuralNetwork()

    print ("Random starting synaptic weights: ")
    print (neural_network.synaptic_weights)

    training_set_inputs = array([
     [0.46,0.4,0.98039216],
     [0.58,0.0,0.98039216],
     [0.2,1.0,0.39215686],
     [0.1,0.4,0.45960784],
     [0.74,0.53333333,0.19607843],
     [0.48,0.93333333,0.0],
     [0.38,0.7,0.98039216],
     [0.02,0.53333333,1.0],
     [0.,0.03333333,0.88235294],
     [1.0,0.8,0.78431373]])

    training_set_outputs = array([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]).T

    neural_network.train(training_set_inputs, training_set_outputs, 10000)

    print ("New synaptic weights after training: ")
    print (neural_network.synaptic_weights)

    print ("Considering new situation [0.5,0.5,0.5] -> ?: ")
    test = [0.5,0.5,0.5]
    print (neural_network.think(array(test)))
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the full code?

Comment: @user2653663 posted it in the question just now. :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have left out the learning rate when you compute the update. Try multiplying the "adjustment" by something like 0.001

```
        error = training_set_outputs - output
        adjustment = training_set_inputs.T.dot(error * self.__sigmoid_derivative(output))

        self.synaptic_weights += adjustment
```

Comment: Unfortunately, all weights are still negative. :( But I sure will add the learning rate anyways!